# No module named torch.nn found

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network, torch

I am following a tutorial on chatbot : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/chatbot_tutorial.html

I have windows 10.

```py
import torch #works
```

but the following imports don't work:

```py
import torch.nn
import torch.jit
```

> Error:
>
> ```
> no module named torch.nn found
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> No module named torch.jit found
> ```

I have installed the following in anaconda :

```sh
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

what should i do to remove the error

The code is:

```py
import torch
from torch.jit import script, trace
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring out the solution or a workaround?

Comment: No i ended u using colab

Answer (score 0):

There.
You have to remove torch. for nn , the command would then become :

`import nn as n`

`import nn.functional as F`

Remove torch. from the commands

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else who ends up here made the same mistake I did, I had a folder I created for my PyTorch related code, which I ingeniously named `torch`. This was causing issues because the `torch` python package wasn't being imported and instead the local directory was being imported.